# Error al paginar en laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un error al paginar los datos, solo carga la primera pagina y luego me da un **MethodNotAllowedHttpException**.

Le he estado dando vueltas y no logro solucionarlo.

Ruta:

```
Route::post('estados/resultado','consultasController@searchestado')->name('consultas.estado.search');
```

Controlador:

```
public function searchestado (Request $request){
    $consulta = Order::Estado($request->state, $request->orden, $request->modo)->paginate(5);
    return view('resultadoConsulta')->with('order',$consulta);
}
```

Scope:

```
public function scopeEstado($query,$estado,$orden,$modo){
    return $query->where('state','=',$estado)
                 ->where('user_id','=',\Auth::user()->id)
                 ->orderBy($orden,$modo);
}
```

Cargando todo **sin paginación funciona bien**, intente paginar en el socope y tampoco me funciono la paginacion correctamente.

Me carga los valores indicados en **paginate(5)** y se renderiza bien la navegación ente paginas pero no se carga el contenido de las otras paginas.

Dejo un DD en el controlador antes de devolver los datos a la vista:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo otras paginaciones que funcionan correctamente, soy relativamente nuevo con este framework y hay algo que estoy pasando por alto, he consultado la documentación pero no logro solucionarlo.

¿Quizá no debería ser con POST por que al agregar el ?page=2 me genera el error?

Intente con GET y tampoco me funciono, al cambiar de pagina los parametos de la consulta se borraron.

URL POST:

```
/consultas/estados/resultado
/consultas/estados/resultado?page=2
```

URL GET:

```
/consultas/estados/resultado?state=En+Camino&orden=buy_date&modo=desc
/consultas/estados/resultado?page=2
```

Mensaje de error al cambiar de pagina:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La paginación debería manejarse por GET preferiblemente, y para preservar los parámetros de búsqueda al cambiar de página, debes llamar los enlaces de paginación de esta forma si lo haces en la vista:

```
{{ $order->appends(request()->input())->links() }}
```

Esta línea lo que hace es agregar los parámetros de entrada del request actual obtenidos con el helper `request()->input()` por medio del método `appends()` a la instancia del paginador `$order`, y por últimos llama al generador de enlaces `links()` el cual no es más que un alias de `render()`.

Comment: Renderizando así en la vista quedan en la url los parámetros pero la paginación sigue fallando :(

Comment: ¿qué continúa fallando? ¿qué error aparece?

Comment: MethodNotAllowedHttpException, Agregué una captura en la descripción

Comment: la ruta está definida en get y la estás llamando por get?

Comment: Ahora la tengo con POST pero he probado todo lo que se me ha ocurrido con ambos métodos y lo que me indicaste más arriba.

Comment: como te dije las búsquedas es mejor hacerlas en post a menos que tengas algún requerimiento específico, que no lo veo en este caso

Comment: Lo tendré en consideración, muchas gracias. Seguiré informándome hasta encontrar el error y comentaré la solución por si luego le sirve a alguien más.

Comment: La solución es la que te estoy dando, pasar todo a get y utilizar appends para no perder los parámetros de búsqueda

Comment: Tenias razón, ahí se ha solucionado con lo que me dijiste.
Ya para finalizar si no es mucha la molestia me podrias explicar esta linea porfavor:

{{ $order->appends(request()->input())->links() }}

Me gusta entender que estoy haciendo

Comment: Lo explicaré en la respuesta.